# SQL Server Regular expression extract pattern from DB colomn

Tags: sql-server, regex, expression

I have a question about SQL Server: I have a database column with a pattern which is like this:

1. up to 10 digits
2. then a comma
3. up to 10 digits
4. then a semicolon

e.g.

```
100000161, 100000031; 100000243, 100000021;
100000161, 100000031; 100000243, 100000021;
```

and I want to extract within the pattern the first digits (up to 10) (1.) and then a semicolon (4.)

(or, in other words, remove everything from the semicolon to the next semicolon)

```
100000161; 100000243; 100000161; 100000243;
```

Can you please advice me how to establish this in SQL Server? Im not very familiar with regex and therefore have no clue how to fix this.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: SQL Server is notorious among the enterprise databases for having fairly lousy regex replace support, which is probably what you would want to be using for this problem.  Is there any chance you could scrub this data somewhere else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No matter how lousy the regex support is, something *this* simple will never be a problem in any regex engine. Regex is also something you would definitely NOT want to use for this task.

Comment: @Tomalak `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is not a SQL Server function, it's a _MySQL_ function, and yes, regex is the sort of thing you would want to use here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: Yes, there is an option to process this another way. As I'm exporting the data into a flat file I could read the data in powershell via the .net file reader and post process the data but I thought it would be just one simple command in SQL (which I would prefer to post-processing the data)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen regex is notorious for bad performance in databases - you need to create the entire parse tree even before you can filter or retrieve that single record. You can easily add a SQLCLR function that performs regex matching but the performance will be *bad*. Fast `STRING_SPLIT`, `STRING_AGG` implementations work character by character to avoid wasting server memory

Comment: @user3898488 are you trying to return the first field from each pair. You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split first by `;`, then by `,`. It would be better if you parsed the data *before* storing it in the database though. You can't take advantage of indexes if you need to apply functions on a column's values

Comment: I just checked string_split; it looks like the DB used is too old and is not supporting this function

Comment: @user3898488 *another* option is to cheat a bit by taking advantage of SQL Server's XML or JSON support, replace `;` and `'` with tags and use XQuery to select the first tag. That's how the fastest string splitting methods worked before `STRING_SPLIT` was introduced.

Comment: The sample data you show does not match the pattern that you wrote.

Comment: Oh, yes your right.. I just realized this while within the application it always shows 10 digits filled up with leading zeros, the database shows it another way.. my bad..

Comment: @user3898488 Are the spaces really there?

Comment: @user3898488 Does "100000161, 100000031; 100000243, 100000021;" represent one or two rows of data? (It could be that the formatting in your question went wrong.)

Comment: Its one row, but I need to update this on lots of rows (e.g. 200.000)

Comment: @user3898488 if you have 200K rows, normalize the table. Or store the original data in a staging table and insert the final data into a *normalized* table. 200K rows are enough that you *do* need indexing support to speed up queries

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Declare @Sql Table (SqlCol nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @Sql
SELECT'100000161,100000031;100000243,100000021;100000161,100000031;100000243,100000021;'
   ;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))         AS Rno, 
                split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Data 
         FROM   (SELECT Cast('<S>' 
                             + Replace( Replace(sqlcol, ';', ','), ',', 
                             '</S><S>') 
                             + '</S>'AS XML) AS Data 
                 FROM   @Sql)AS A 
                CROSS apply data.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)) 
SELECT Stuff((SELECT '; ' + data 
              FROM   cte 
              WHERE  rno%2 <> 0 
                     AND data <> '' 
              FOR xml path ('')), 1, 2, '') AS ExpectedData 

ExpectedData
-------------
100000161; 100000243; 100000161; 100000243
```

Comment: You don't need all this to extract the first value. Use different inner and outer tags instead of a single `<S>` and select the one you want

Comment: This looks good. The only issue I realize here when I checked on real data was that the outbut of select column from table is written into one line while the source data is in different rows?

Comment: @user3898488 what *do* you want? All results in a single row? A pair per input row?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will get you what you are after as long as that pattern truly holds.  If not it's fairly easy to ensure it does conform to that pattern and then apply this

```
Select Substring(TargetCol, 1, 10) + ';' From TargetTable
```

Comment: OP changed the spec a little, so it would now be `SELECT LEFT(TargetCol, CHARINDEX(',', TargetCol) - 1) + ';' WHERE CHARINDEX(',', TargetCol) BETWEEN 1 AND 11;`.

Comment: This looks pretty good, but where do i have add the from targettable? I checked your first command and it runs fine, but im failing in merging your two commands

Comment: @user3898488 Oops! I tested with a variable and changed the name without adding in the FROM, so... `SELECT LEFT(TargetCol, CHARINDEX(',', TargetCol) - 1) + ';' FROM SomeTable WHERE CHARINDEX(',', TargetCol) BETWEEN 1 AND 11;`. But that won't help if you have more than one pair of data in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of SQL Server's XML support to convert the input string into an XML value and query it with XQuery and XPath expressions.

For example, the following query will replace each `;` with `</b><a>` and each `,` to `</a><b>` to turn each string into `<a>100000161</a><a>100000243</a><a />`. After that, you can select individual `<a>` nodes with `/a[1]`, `/a[2]` :

```
declare @table table (it nvarchar(200))

insert into @table values
('100000161, 100000031; 100000243, 100000021;'),
('100000161, 100000031; 100000243, 100000021;')

select 
    xCol.value('/a[1]','nvarchar(200)'), 
    xCol.value('/a[2]','nvarchar(200)')
from (
    select convert(xml, '<a>' 
                        + replace(replace(replace(it,';','</b><a>'),',','</a><b>'),' ','')
                        + '</a>')
                  .query('a') as xCol
    from @table) as tmp 

-------------------------
A1          A2
100000161   100000243
100000161   100000243
```

`value` extracts a single value from an XML field. `nodes` returns a table of nodes that match the XPath expression. The following query will return all "keys" :

```
select 
    a.value('.','nvarchar(200)')
from (
    select convert(xml, '<a>' 
                        + replace(replace(replace(it,';','</b><a>'),',','</a><b>'),' ','')
                        + '</a>')
                  .query('a') as xCol
    from @table) as tmp 
    cross apply xCol.nodes('a') as y(a)
where a.value('.','nvarchar(200)')<>''

------------
100000161
100000243
100000161
100000243
```

With 200K rows of data though, I'd seriously consider transforming the data when loading it and storing it in indivisual, indexable columns, or add a *separate*, related table. Applying string manipulation functions on a column means that the server can't use any covering indexes to speed up queries.

If that's not possible (why?) I'd consider at least adding a separate XML-typed column that would contain the same data in XML form, to allow the creation of an XML index.